# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error - Date format error?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, parseexception

I am storing the current date in SQLite db using the variable CURRENT_DATE. I found that the date format used is `yyyy-mm-dd` in the same. I want to parse the date in the code but I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error:
>               at java.util.Date.parseError

The code is shown below:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    String formattedTaskDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(dateStoredAsStringFetchedFromDB));
    Date d = new Date(formattedTaskDate);
```

At first, I am fetching the date from the database and storing it in a String variable (because date is stored as TEXT in SQLite) and then I am performing the above operations but I get the exception as **parseError**.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please take note of my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your date format is wrong. You should take note that the uppercase `M` is used to represent months and the lowercase `m` is used for minutes. To solve this just change your `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyy-MM-dd`.

Now if you want to change that format in the future you may do so by doing something like this :

```
try {
     DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
     Date input = inputFormat.parse(date);
     DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEEE MMMM-dd-yyyy ", Locale.ENGLISH);
     String finaldate = outputFormat.format(input);
            txtDate.setText(finaldate); <-- just an example of displaying the date 
     }catch (Exception ex) {
            Alerts.CatchError(getBaseContext(), ex.toString());
     }
```

This will display the initially stored date of `2015-04-25 12:08:34` ( yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ) as `Friday April-25-2015`. You can of course change this to your liking as well, just refer to the documentation Ankit has kindly linked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Format is wrong, try this:

```
String string = dateStoredAsStringFetchedFromDB;
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(string);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please paste the value of `dateStoredAsStringFetchedFromDB` as returned from the database ?
It's probable that the returned value does not match the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Also please note that from the javadoc (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) the 'm' pattern denotes minutes and not month as you seem to expect.