# Parse Error while parsing date in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

As a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852231/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parse-error-unable-to-parse-date-in-androi?noredirect=1#comment47831274_29852231) question, the error doesn't seem to be resolved. The date in SQLite is stored as `2015-04-25` which is of the form `yyyy-MM-dd`. Now this date (which is system date) is stored in the db using CURRENT_DATE variable and fetched as a string. The minimal code is as shown below:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date taskDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date("2015-04-25")));
```

But I get an exception as:

> Parse error: 2015-04-25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this working code.

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedCode = formatter.format("supply your date-time here");
```

I believe you should either add time along with your date when you supply your input or you have to remove `HH:mm:ss` part.

Comment: I need to remove the HH:mm:ss part :)